# Sorting projects in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to sort projects in Package (or Project) Exporer View by project state (opened or closed?). 
I know about working sets, but it's not actually what I want :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should take a second look at working sets, in my humble opinion that is the best way to organize projects. If you set `Top level elements` to `working sets` in the dropdown menu in either explorer , all projects will be sorted under the working set.

Anyway, the sorting order cannot be changed as far as I know, but you can choose to hide closed projects in Package explorer. In the drop down menu, go to `Filters` and choose to hide closed projects.